# Certificate not passing in HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, certificate, httpclient

I need to pass a certificate in .NET Core using C# through `HttpClient` but I'm getting a response of "400 No required SSL certificate was sent".

This is my code - please suggest a solution, as I am new to using `HttpClient`:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\\Pradeep\\Docs\mycertificate.pfx", "12345");

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    using (var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), URL))
    {
        request1.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("appID", appId);
        request1.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("timestamp", timeStamp);
        request1.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accesskey", token);

        string jsonconvert = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JSonFormat);
        request1.Content = new StringContent(jsonconvert);

        request1.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage result = _httpClient.PostAsync(URL, request1.Content).Result;

        string returnValue = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var response1 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request1);
    }
}
```

Also check the response in this screenshot:

[image: Response Image]

Answer (score 1):

You've created your `HttpClient` in the beginning, including the handler for sending along the certificate:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\\Pradeep\\Docs\mycertificate.pfx", "12345");

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
```

yet, later on - you're suddenly creating *another* `HttpClient` instance (*without* assigning the certificate-passing handler....) and use that to make the `PostAsync` call:

```
    HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage result = _httpClient.PostAsync(URL, request1.Content).Result;
```

**OF COURSE** the certificate won't be sent along! You've created a `HttpClient` instance, without any mechanism to handle and pass the certificate....

Why don't you just use the HTTP client instance you've created in the beginning??

```
    // comment out this instantiation - not needed
    // HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
    // make the call with the "httpClient" from the beginning!
    // Also: use "await" - and not the .Result kludge ....
    HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.PostAsync(URL, request1.Content);
```

This should now work and pass along the certificate with your call.